# Regarding VM argument setting in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I once saw a VM argument setting in eclipse as  `-Xmx256m -d64`. I know Xmx is used to setup the heap size, but what does `-d64` for?

Answer (score 4):

The argument `-d64` enables you run `64bit VM`

Reference:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#How_to_run_on_64bit_VM_while_the_native_SWT_are_32bit